# How to call a function that moves the cursor without leaving visual mode?

Tags: vim

I have a function that moves the cursor with the built-in `cursor()` function and it works fine on normal mode.
For concreteness suppose that this is the function:

```
function! F()
    call cursor( line('.')+1, 1)
endfunction
```

used with a mappings as:

```
 nnoremap <buffer> a :call F()<cr>
```

Now I want to reuse this function to move the cursor on any visual mode (visual, line visual, and block visual) and without losing the previous selection.

For example, with an initial buffer in visual mode (`c` means the cursor is at a line, `v` means the line is part of the current visual selection):

```
vc 1
   2
   3
```

hitting `a` would give:

```
v  1
vc 2
   3
```

and hitting `a` again would give:

```
v  1
v  2
vc 3
```

so the old selection was kept.

I would like to reuse `F()` as much as possible, since in my application `F()` is quite large.
What is the best way to do that?

Up to now, the best I could do was use a wrapper function:

```
function! VisMove(f)
    normal! gv
    call function(a:f)()
endfunction
```

and map as:

```
 vnoremap <buffer> a :call VisMove('F')<cr>
```

however I am not satisfied because this:

1. It requires putting the annoying wrapper on every new fgplugin I write.
2. Calling a function that moves the cursor (or has other arbitrary side effects) without ever leaving visual (current) mode seems like such a natural thing to be able to do. There is even already `<expr>` which almost does it, but it resets cursor position.

Comment: I can't think of a different workaround off the top of my head; I think any visual map would lose its visual selection.

Comment: I must resist the urge of making all the commands in your question more readable.

Comment: In visual mode, the cursor is either at the beginning or at the end of the selection, are you trying to expand/retract the selection to an arbitrary point?

Comment: @romainl done expanding commands, added example of desired behaviour. I want to move the end of the selection to an arbitrary point (supposing end is the side that moves when you hit say `j`, and beginning is the side that did not move)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve this by passing a `mode` argument (or alternatively a boolean `isVisual` flag) into the function:

```
fu! F(mode) range
    if a:mode ==# 'v'
        normal! gv
    endif
    ...
endf
nn <buffer> a :cal F('n')<cr>
vn <buffer> a :cal F('v')<cr>
```

Comment: thanks Ingo, but I think I prefer my current solution of adding a single wrapper for all functions instead of adding one extra arg and the `if` clause to every movement function.